# Using Tokens with Username/Password Combo

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, api

I'm trying to figure out a way to integrate both tokens and username/password combo into a rails API. The front-end of the API is an iOS app which requires username/password combination to keep track of user's profiles.

Following [thoughtbot/ios-on-rails](https://github.com/thoughtbot/ios-on-rails/) github repo along with [thoughtbot's iOS on Rails](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/welcome-aboard-youre-riding-ios-on-rails) book, I am able to create a user's model by using device tokens to handle authentication.

However, as noted by the thoughtbot team:

> Our app doesn’t require username/password login, instead we will
>   create a user object on the first run of the app and then consistently
>   sign our requests as this user. This behavior is useful for apps that
>   don’t require login, or have some sort of guest mode.

Here is the migration file for such token based authentication API:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.timestamps null: false
      t.string :device_token
    end

    add_index :users, :device_token
  end
end
```

In my case, I'm building an iOS app that does require username/password login on the client and I need to create the database schema in rails to handle this. Here is how I'm thinking of building this:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.timestamps null: false
      t.string :first_name, null: false
      t.string :last_name, null: false
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
class CreateTokens < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tokens do |t|
      t.timestamps null: false
      t.string :device_token
    end
  end
end
```

with the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tokens
end
```

and

```
class Token < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I am on the right track? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that looks about right, may want to use a table name called authentication_tokens as the following post suggests

http://www.brianauton.com/posts/token-authentication-devise.html